# Display of the table data in pivots or non-pivotal forms

Tags: excel, pivot-table

[image]

And my future report should contain as below.

Region  --> Filter list of Regions

If I select North America
I should be able to display 
Country Name
List of states down from here
(non-Null data should be displayed)

( i tried with pivot tables but results are not in expected format)

Comment: What version of Excel are you using and are you familiar with powerquery? Essentially, you want to unpivot the state column and then do a table fill down on Region and Country Name columns. Then you can use a pivot.

Comment: Excel for Mac- Office 2017

Comment: No, I don't see it on my mac. not so good.but a question on the pivot is,  If I move my states to pivot every state becomes a column then I will see a lot of blanks for others. how would it help me keep the data in the format I want? powerquery has in built-in solutions?

Comment: I have another windows computer. pls, tell me what to do with it? I will do for few thousand columns and rows, not a simple one as shown in the example.

Comment: Powerquery does have inbult functions. But looks like it is not available to mac. But you could achieve this through VBA especially if your data is set up as a table. There is a blog [here](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2016/08/18/quick-ways-unpivot-excel-data/) that outlines ways of unpivoting data (including more than just powerquery). This could be combined with a table fill down to populate the other columns. There are also online macros to perform this sort of operation as it is a frequent query from people who have received pivoted data where row headings are not repeated.

Comment: Another link here http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/

Comment: Set your data up as an Excel table (Ctrl+T), Windows machine goto powerquery tab (pre 2016) or get & transform 2016. Query > data from table > pull up your table. Window that opens highlight the state column > right click > unpivot column, then with the Region column highlighted, Transform tab > Any column > Fill > click down arrow to expand then > Down. This will fill down the column with the value above. Repeat this for your Country Name column. Rename Attribute column as State.  Home tab > close and load to sheet > create pivot off new table which will have data in required format.

Comment: columns of the table would be around 70 but rows  will upto 5,000 to 7,000

Comment: That would be fine. You should be able to Google to check the steps but i have outlined above how i would do it.

Comment: P.S. You will be able to right click on the State column and remove rows with NULLs which will get rid of gaps.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and help @QHarr I will google find the more information as required.

Comment: It’s fine. If a full answer isn’t posted by tomorrow I will post back with some images to help you.

Comment: i tried to test using dummy data using pivoting... please see and tell me how to get rid of nulls

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ar-Vl2jvSR3bgTxvqxUjyk47PzqN here is the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a guide to using Powerquery to complete the task

1) Turn your source data into an Excel table. Select a cell in the data area and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd>. Remember to select `my table has headers`.

[image: Creating a table]

2) Go to Get And Transform 2016 or PowerQuery tab (you have to install add-in  pre-2016) > New query `from table`

[image: New query from table]

3) Highlight third column hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and then select the end column to highlight all `States` columns then right click > `unpivot columns`

[image: Select and unpivot states columns]

4) Select `Attribute` column > right click > `Remove column` then select `Value` column and rename as `State`

5) Then select `Region` column > `Transform` tab > `Any Column` > `Fill` > `Fill Down`

[image: Table fill down to complete column entries]

6) Repeat for `Country` column

7) Top left corner > `Close and load to` . Here you have number of options which include (there are more ways to create the final pivot):

a)  You could create `connection only` and tick the add to data model check box and then use Power pivot to directly access the new table for  a pivot

b) You can `close and load to` a new worksheet choosing to `view as a Table`

I will show you option b.

[image: Close and load to table]

You end up with a flat table in a new worksheet

[image: Flat table]

8) Select a cell within the table and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd> to create a new pivottable.

noting the different options you could use for setting up this pivottable.

[image: Creating pivottable]

9) Arrange pivottable as required

[image: Filtering by Region]

No nulls need to be removed in this case. However, you could have selected the down arrow next to the column header of interest and then selected `Remove Empty`.

[image: Remove Nulls if required]

Comment: thank you very much for this discription, i will try on windows system and let you know@QHarr